# How do I remove ace-of-penguins without removing lubuntu-desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, uninstall, default-programs

I desperately need to get more disk space and I thought I should remove `ace-of-penguins`. But when I try to remove it in Synaptic it wants me to mark `lubuntu-desktop` for removal as well. (This also happens when I try to remove Abiword and anything else that came with Lubuntu.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had no problems because of its removal in Lubuntu 12.10. It's considered a "meta package" and not of any consequence.

You can read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveLubuntuDesktop.

To quote from there:

> When you want to remove a program from lubuntu, you may be told that by doing so it will remove lubuntu-desktop. The package lubuntu-desktop is only used for the installation of lubuntu and can safely be removed.
>
> Lubuntu-desktop is what is called a meta-package which, simply put, is just a list of what to install. It is a design decision that all packages included in lubuntu-desktop depend on it, so as to be able to use --no-install-recommends option when the initial installation occurs, thus preventing non-essential programs being installed.

And here is more on the subject: [Re: [Lubuntu-desktop] lubuntu-desktop metapackage - Recommends vs Dependencies](http://www.mail-archive.com/lubuntu-desktop@lists.launchpad.net/msg03490.html).

Comment: Very helpful since the Ubuntu 12.10 release for Toshiba AC100 comes with lubuntu-desktop and ace-of-penguins preinstalled.